# Consistency re what counts as opinion?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why is the second post a matter of opinion but not the first one?

[What do theoretical physicists need from computer scientists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27209/what-do-theoretical-physicists-need-from-computer-scientists?rq=1)

[Do physicists need to study functional analysis in depth in 2024?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/807013/do-physicists-need-to-study-functional-analysis-in-depth-in-2024)

Comment: One reason is that the community is different than it was 13 years ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "different"?  And why isn't the old one closed?

Comment: While some people have been active on the site for 13+ years, it probably isn't that many. As people come and go the community standards change. Further, that question was asked less than a year after the site started. It isn't closed because nobody bothers trawling through 13-year old questions looking for ones to close. If that Q is your main argument, I'm not buying it.

Comment: Further, that Q had a well defined scope, based on a paper from the OP. Your question is not very well focused. For example, I have never studied, nor used, functional analysis which has not harmed me in 40 years of my career.

Comment: Funny enough, 3 people tried closing it back in 2013, as you can [plainly see in the timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/27209/timeline). Also, it looks like that post came from the now-defunct theoretical physics site (due to the user names not of the form `user######` and are not links to user pages) that had different policies than this site.

Comment: @Jon Custer: The question was not rhetorical and thus can't be an argument.  You have yet to state any principle..  It was obviously meant to be a quite broad, hence unfocussed, question.  Find somebody else to be rude to.

Comment: @Kyle: What exactly is the relevant policy?

Comment: At https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/review-close one finds: "is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer". Some physicist would benefit from studying a certain math field, others won't.

Comment: @mster8390 In addition to the link Jon gave, see also [Closed Questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). I was still quite the newbie back in 2013 (barely 6M by the time that question came in) and wasn't even aware of TP site until much later so I couldn't tell you anything about their site (except that every SE site's users behave differently).

Comment: *It was obviously meant to be a quite broad, hence unfocussed, question.* Well, that’s a problem on this site. If your question hadn’t been closed for being opinion-based, it probably would have been closed for being unfocused. Take a look at the subreasons available under the “Needs improvement” flag; the one above “Opinion-based”  is “Needs more focus”.